# how to convert id datatype in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like

```
id
27.45
29.1
27.45
21.95
18.1
51.75
0
21.45
41.94
21.95
32.95
```

My query is

```
SUM(CASE WHEN ab.dates BETWEEN bc.fst_sales_date AND BC.[WEEK4] THEN
[salesval] -- my initial try  
ELSE 0 END) week4_qtyvalues
```

facing error

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '41.94' to data
>   type int.

I have checked

```
SUM(CASE WHEN ab.dates BETWEEN bc.fst_sales_date AND BC.[WEEK4] THEN
CONVERT(float,[salesval]) -- this is what I've tried  
ELSE 0 end) week4_qtyvalues
```

and

```
SUM(CASE WHEN ab.dates between bc.fst_sales_date AND BC.[WEEK4] THEN
CAST([salesval]AS int) -- this is what I've tried  
ELSE 0 END) week4_qtyvalues
```

Regardless of my tries , I'm still facing the same error.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (id VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @t (id)
VALUES
    ('27.45'),('29.1'),('27.45'),('21.95'),('18.1'),
    ('51.75'),('0'),('21.45'),('41.94'),('21.95'),('32.95')

SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN id IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(id AS FLOAT) ELSE 0 END)
FROM @t
```

Answer (score 1):

That is happening because you have a nvarchar and not a float number to cast to int. You should first cast the [salesval] to float and after that cast it to int. Something like this:

```
CAST(CAST([salesval] AS float) AS INT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way SQL Server handles statements with multiple data types mixed together, it'll still try to take your salesval field and treat it as an int.

So, firstly, try casting the 0 as well.

And secondly, you almost certainly don't want to use float - it's for scientific calculations that need its huge range only and isn't precise. Try decimal instead.